# Save and load float values in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am applying a filter to an image, which results in a filter responses that are not in the range [0 255]. I store them in a CvMat of type IPL_DEPTH_64F. I tried to save it with:

```
FileStorage fs(outFile, FileStorage::WRITE);
fs.open(outFile, FileStorage::WRITE);       
fs << "filter" << filter_mat;    
fs.release();
```

Unfortunately this results in a file with values between 0-255. Obviously this then cannot be loaded properly!
So the question is: How to you save such a matrix as it should be? And how can it be loaded again with OpenCV? There seems to be hardly any documentation available!

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: In which range *are* your filter responses?

Comment: Are you sure you have the type set correctly (CV_64FC1) ? cv::Filestorage certainly stores floats for a small matrix. I don't know if there is a switch over for image sized matrices

Comment: the values are in range of 0-255.
I create it with  cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,IPL_DEPTH_64F). When I store the values in the matrice and reread them. thez are still correct. It's only when writing them!
The matrice is not oversized. It is around 800x600. 
Apart from that, it the above code the way to do it?

Comment: If you are creating your filter with cvCreate*** then you are mixing the old C and the new C++ APIs. You should use directly a cv::Mat instead to avoid any possible problems. You can save huge floating-point matrices with OpenCV, I've done it before, there is no switch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the error! I created the matrix using the type **IPL_DEPTH_64F**. When I changed it to **CV_64FC1** it worked.
Thanks Martin for your help :)